# my code stop working after the 4th choice

Tags: c++

my code stop working if the user made the 4-5-6 choice in my c++ app

i tried restart it many times and it not work
i rewrite it too and is not working
i speak french so many things is in french sorry

```
//sorry im french i translate the most importants things
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::cout << R"(Bienvenue dans le convertisseur universel L&A industries)";
    int e, x, y;
    double z, a, b;


    std::cout << "\nthere is the choices de of conversions:\n\n";
    std::cout << "   1.Tax   2.Temperature  3.Longueur \n";
    std::cout << "   4.speed  5.Mass  6.Frequency\n\n";
    std::cout << "Quelle conversion voulez-vous faire ?";
    std::cin >> x;
    if (x == 1) {
        std::cout << "Vous avez choisi : Taxes\n";
        x = 1.15;
    enter code here
        std::cout << "Entrez l'argent($): ";
        std::cin >> z;
        a = z * 1.15;
        std::cout << "Avec les taxes votre somme reviens a :  " << a << "\n";
        if (z == 0) {
            std::cout << "Erreur";
        }
    }
    else if (x == 2) {
        std::cout << "Quel unite de mesure voulez-vous utiliser? 1.Celsius > Farenheit 2.Farenheit > Celsius :\n";
        std::cin >> e;
        if (e == 1) {

            std::cout << "Entrez votre Temperature en celsius: ";
            std::cin >> b;
            y = b * 9 / 5 + 32;
            std::cout << "Votre Temperature est de : " << y << " °F\n";
        }
        else if (e == 2) {
            std::cout << "Entrez votre Temperature en Farenheit: ";
            std::cin >> x;
            y = (x - 32) * 5 / 9;
            std::cout << "Votre Temperature est de : " << y << " °C\n";



        }
    }
    else if (x == 3) {
        std::cout << "Quel unite de mesure voulez-vous utiliser : 1.Metre vers pied  2.Pieds vers metre\n";
        std::cin >> e;
        if (e == 1) {

            std::cout << "Entrez votre longueur en metres :";
            std::cin >> x;
            y = x * 3.281;
            std::cout << "Votre longueur est de  : " << y << " pi \n";

        }

        else if (e == 2) {
            std::cout << "Entrez votre longueur en Pieds :";
            std::cin >> x;
            y = x / 3.281;
            std::cout << "Votre longueur est de  : " << y << " m \n";

        }
        else if (x == 4)
        {
            std::cout << "Entrez votre longueur en Pieds :";
            std::cin >> x;
            y = x / 3.281;
            std::cout << "Votre longueur est de  : " << y << " m \n";




        }
        while (true) {

            system("pause");
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

'

the program stop if i answer 4-5-6
number is the value we attribute to "X"
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Your code doesn't handle choices #4, #5, and #6 at all, it is only handling #1, #2, and #3.  Also, why do you have `system("pause");` in an endless loop? It shouldn't be in a loop at all. And you are calling `system("pause");` and `return 0;` only in your #3 handler. I think your #3 handler is missing a needed `}` before `else if (x == 4)`

Comment: You might want to change to a switch statement (maybe with an enum so the code is a bit more self-documenting) and create functions for each case. You also got some implicit conversions here and there, not sure if intentional...

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't seem to handle choices 5 or 6 at all. It attempts to handle choice x==4 but fails as you're missing a closing brace for the x==3 option.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::cout << R"(Bienvenue dans le convertisseur universel L&A industries)";
    int e, x, y;
    double z, a, b;


    std::cout << "\nthere is the choices de of conversions:\n\n";
    std::cout << "   1.Tax   2.Temperature  3.Longueur \n";
    std::cout << "   4.speed  5.Mass  6.Frequency\n\n";
    std::cout << "Quelle conversion voulez-vous faire ?";
    std::cin >> x;
    if (x == 1) {
        std::cout << "Vous avez choisi : Taxes\n";
        x = 1.15; //This should be a double since you have a decimal 
        //enter code here
            std::cout << "Entrez l'argent($): ";
        std::cin >> z;
        a = z * 1.15;
        std::cout << "Avec les taxes votre somme reviens a :  " << a << "\n"; //
        if (z == 0) 
        {
            std::cout << "Erreur";
        }
    }
    else if (x == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Quel unite de mesure voulez-vous utiliser? 1.Celsius > Farenheit 2.Farenheit > Celsius :\n";
        std::cin >> e;
        if (e == 1) {

            std::cout << "Entrez votre Temperature en celsius: ";
            std::cin >> b;
            y = b * 9 / 5 + 32;
            std::cout << "Votre Temperature est de : " << y << " °F\n";
        }
        else if (e == 2) {
            std::cout << "Entrez votre Temperature en Farenheit: ";
            std::cin >> x;
            y = (x - 32) * 5 / 9;
            std::cout << "Votre Temperature est de : " << y << " °C\n";



        }
    }
    else if (x == 3) //Vous n'avez jamais fermé cette boucle - Voir ci-dessous
    {
        std::cout << "Quel unite de mesure voulez-vous utiliser : 1.Metre vers pied  2.Pieds vers metre\n";
        std::cin >> e;
        if (e == 1) {

            std::cout << "Entrez votre longueur en metres :";
            std::cin >> x;
            y = x * 3.281;
            std::cout << "Votre longueur est de  : " << y << " pi \n";

        }

        else if (e == 2)
        {
            std::cout << "Entrez votre longueur en Pieds :";
            std::cin >> x;
            y = x / 3.281;
            std::cout << "Votre longueur est de  : " << y << " m \n";

        }
        else if (x == 4)
        {
            std::cout << "Entrez votre longueur en Pieds :";
            std::cin >> x;
            y = x / 3.281;
            std::cout << "Votre longueur est de  : " << y << " m \n";




        }
    } //Vous avez besoin de ça ici


        //Vous n'en avez pas besoin ici. Pas de boucle en boucle - boucle fermée

    //  while (true) { - DELETE

            system("pause");
    //  } - DELETE

        return 0;
    }
```